# Map Annotation in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

What annotation should go on the creditBalances field of the User class?

credit_balance table

```
CREATE TABLE `credit_balance` (
  `user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `currency` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Credit class

```
@Embeddable
public class Credit {
  @Column(name="currency", columnDefinition="CHAR(3)", nullable=false)
  Currency currency;
  @Column(name="amount", columnDefinition="DECIMAL(12,4)", nullable=false)
  BigDecimal amount;
}
```

User class

```
@Entity
public class User {
  @Id
  String id;

  //What annotation goes here?
  Map<Currency, Credit> creditBalances;
}
```

We are using Hibernate 3.4.

I've looked through http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.4/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association-collections but get lost quickly.

Clarification: The `currency` column should be used for both the map key and the currency field of the `Credit` object.

Is this possible in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

This is one variant I use. In general the `@ElementCollection` or `@ManyToMany` annotations are used, the others are situational.

```
@ElementCollection
@Column(name = "value", nullable=false)
@MapKeyColumn(name="name")
@JoinTable(name = "from_to", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "to_id"))
Map<String, String>
```

Comment: ElementCollection was added in 3.5.  How do I do this in 3.4?  Also as an embeddable, Credit does not have an id or its own table for that matter.

Comment: `@CollectionOfElements`. Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-ofvalues) for embedding.